# Nuxt 3 and Vue 3 onMounted call function useFetch function not getting data form APIs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

Hi i am new in Nuxt and Vue. I am using Nuxt framework to get data form APIs. I want to get data from APIs when onMounted method call.

I created saprate function to call api. That api get data with product id.
If i call API without onMounted method it is working fine but when i call function in OnMounted method it is not working. always get "null" value.

Code given blew

```
<script setup>

    const product = async (id) => {
      
       const { data, pending, error } = await useFetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`);
      
      console.log("after this" + id);
      console.log(data.value);
      
   }; 

    onMounted(async () => { 
      product(2); 
      
    });
</script>

Otuput in console
after this 2
null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is due to `onMounted` but [it seems to be a timing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75361708/11258206)

Using `nextTick` as follows solve the issue:

```js
import { nextTick } from 'vue';

onMounted(async () => {

  await nextTick();

  await getProduct(2);
});
```

I created a working reproduction for you to test [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-jjpgyi?file=pages%2Findex.vue)

Answer (score 0):

Went actually through the same error, and always using `nextTick` seemed wrong.

The real reasons behind this is the misuse of the `useFetch` which is reactive and shoud be used only in the root part of the setup script.
If you use `$fetch` the problem won't appear.

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13471#issuecomment-1889647593