# None of the fetch APIs work on page refresh or on direct page access. Only with server option set to false. How do I fetch on server side then?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a simple UserList component which requests all users from a server and displays them:

```
<script setup>
  const { data: users, pending, error, refresh} = await useFetch("api/getAllUsers");
</script>
```

But data is fetched only when I navigate to the page (with that UserList component) from other page via NuxtLink. If I refresh the page or access the page directly, I won't get any data.

I tried all Nuxt fetch APIs, but the only solution was to use **server: false** like this:

```
const { data: users, pending } = await useLazyFetch("api/getAllUsers", { 
  server: false 
});
```

Or when I use nextTick (thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76527094/nuxt-3-and-vue-3-onmounted-call-function-usefetch-function-not-getting-data-form/76528467#76528467)). But this solution is very inconvenient:

```
const users = ref();
const pending = ref();

onMounted(async () => {
  await nextTick();

  const { data, pending: pend, error, refresh } = await useFetch("api/getAllUsers");

  users.value = data.value;
  pending.value = pend.value;
});
```

Why doesn't fetching on a server side work? I have tons on components that need fetched data. And all the pages that use those components are available directly. Or, of course, could be refreshed. Does it mean that every component have to fetch data on a client side? I think they don't have to. But how do I fix this problem then?

Comment: the first example worked for me: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-eejtkq?file=pages%2Findex.vue)

Comment: I checked your demo and yes, it works. But I cloned it and ran on my computer and faced the same problem